# Generics List with string classname

Tags: java, generics

How do I declare a list with the class name in a string. For eg: I have a className variable with the name of a class. I need to create  List with the type in the className variable.

```
String className ="com.foo.Foo";
```

Is it possible to have a list that is having the same result of

```
List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
```

without knowing the type at the time of declaration.

Comment: Multipart question: *How do I declare a list with the class name in a string*: You could look into the class loader, else this is not the way to do this. *Is it possible to have a list that is having the same result*: Yes, it is: Just use `List fooList = new ArrayList();` and cast the results when accessing the list (it is now just a list of (unchecked) Objects)

Comment: It sounds wrong. I may suppose that there is a method using reflection, but how will you use this list? How will you work in your code with something of unknown type?

Comment: Java uses [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). At execution time, the generic types are not present so... why don't create a `List<Object>` (which in most cases is, what the compiler make out of `List<Something>` anyway thanks to Type Erasure)?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen The second part as an example given to illustrate my question.  I guess I should have been more clearer. In my case what I wanted, is to declared a list with what is there in the class name variable which is known only at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear, but it sounds like you're talking about making a list whose generic type parameter is determined at runtime, e.g. it could be a `List<Foo>` during one run and a `List<Bar>` during another.

You can't do that; type-checking, including generics, is done at compile time.  It's the same reason you can't have a variable whose type is `String` during one run and `Integer` during another.

If you want to be able to choose different types at runtime, the generic type parameter has to be a supertype of all the types you might choose.  For example, you could have a `List<Object>`, and put `Foo` instances in it during one run, and `Bar` instances during another.

Comment: The type-checking at compile time is not the reason you cannot determine generics at runtime (C++ does type-checkin at compile time and there your can determine generics at runtime). The actual reason is [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: It's not specific to generics:  the type of every variable, generic or not, must be known at compile time.  That's true in C++ as well.  (And note that C++ doesn't actually have generics; it has templates, which use similar syntax but work very differently.)  You can have a `List<?>` variable that can refer to either a `List<Foo>` or `List<Bar>`, chosen at runtime, but you can't add any elements to it because the compiler doesn't know what type of objects it requires.

Answer (score 0):

Multipart question "*How do I declare a list with the class name in a string*": you can not declare like in that way. for "*Is it possible to have a list that is having the same result of*": you can create something like "List fooList = new ArrayList();" But you should be take care of the type casting while accessing the fooList.

Comment: The second part as an example given to illustrate my question.  I guess I should have been more clearer. In my case what I wanted, is to declared a list with what is there in the class name variable which is known only at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson has this issue and solves it like this

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference<List<String>>
```